# AdMob Adview to a class which contains an inner class

Tags: android, view, admob, adview

I have an inner class which extends View class inside my activity. Am setting content View as the innerclass view. I want to add an AdView to myactivity. which is a banner.. can anybody help me to achive this? Am new to android..

Class MyActivity extends Activity
{

```
  View myView;

     OnCreate()
      {
       myView= new ViewClass(this);
       setContentView(myView);
      }


   Class ViewClass extends View
     {
       //drawing inside a canvas and other drawing activities
     }
```

}

Now I want to add a AdView to the screen. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml add your view class like

Let's name it `myLayout.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<package.MyActivity$ViewClass android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>

<LinearLayout/>



@Override
  onCreate()
  {
   setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
   myView= (ViewClass)findViewById(R.id.viewClass);

  }
```

More information on [creating a view class](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).

Comment: I Have edited the question by adding some sample code.. Can you have a glance to that?

Comment: So dude, how can i get the stuffs drawn in the ViewClass class? it contains a canvas, and several images drawn to it. If we set the contentView to myLayout, it will only show the specified things in that only rght? Thanks in advance

Comment: myLayout.xml contains the reference to ViewClass which will be drawn on setContentView.

Comment: Yes I tried to do that am getting error for that.. it seems we need to make the inner class static for this. but it has several reference to the non static outer class.. so I found thats the first problem

Comment: So can you help me to add the inner class view to the relative layout of the outer class?

Comment: Dont we need to have a View tag in the xml?

Comment: You can keep a static Context as a variable which u can access in ur inner class. You need to keep view tag as defined in my answer above.

Comment: dude, just one doubt. can we test our app with the real AdId we bought? I am testin it with test ADId. Thanks

Comment: You can test but don't click on live ads.